# what is the difference between 'property' and 'attribute' in Selenium WebElement?

Tags: selenium

Selenium WebElement has 2 methods, in Python, they are 'get_attribute' and 'get_property' . The documentation is very simple and unclear to me.

What is the difference of them on earth?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properties and Attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: They are not selenium-specific terms. The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/604131) to the linked question explains the difference.

Comment: The minimal documentation for [get_property()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_property) also using the bogus property `text_length` was the root of my confusion. Much clearer if they'd used `text_length = len(target_element.get_property("innerText"))`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An **attribute** is a static attribute of a given DOM node, as where a **property** is a computed property of the DOM node object. An example of a **property** would be the `checked` state of a checkbox, or `value` or an input field. As where an **attribute** would be `href` of an anchor tag or the `type` of an input DOM.

```
<a href="https://google.com" id="hello">Hello World</a>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" checked>
<input type="text" id="bar" value="cheesecake">
```

---

```
link_location = document.querySelector('#hello').getAttribute('href')
// # href="https://google.com"

input_checkbox = document.querySelector('#foo').getAttribute('type')
// # type="checkbox"

checkbox_checked = document.querySelector('#foo').checked
// # computed property of the DOM node

textbox_value = document.querySelector('#bar').value
// # computed property of the DOM node
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score 2):

Seems that `get_attribute` search for properties **and then** attributes and `get_property` **just** for properties.

From code [documentation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py)

**get_property**

```
 def get_property(self, name):
        """
        Gets the given property of the element.
        :Args:
            - name - Name of the property to retrieve.
```

**get_attribute**

```
 def get_attribute(self, name):
        """Gets the given attribute or property of the element.
        This method will first try to return the value of a property with the
        given name. If a property with that name doesn't exist, it returns the
        value of the attribute with the same name. If there's no attribute with
        that name, ``None`` is returned.
        Values which are considered truthy, that is equals "true" or "false",
        are returned as booleans.  All other non-``None`` values are returned
        as strings.  For attributes or properties which do not exist, ``None``
        is returned.
        :Args:
            - name - Name of the attribute/property to retrieve.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually explain the differencel. It says what the methods do, but not what results you can expect. For that you need to explain the difference between properties and attributes, which is already explained elsewhere.

Comment: This answer is specific to Python (not to Selenium). For example, in `thirty_four` crate (= library) in Rust, `get_attribute()` can only retrieve static attributes whereas `get_property()` can only retrieve dynamic attributes.